# calculate new column on factor level based on two data.frames/data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to calculate a value for a new column for data.table `dt`. One part of the calculation comes from data.frame `df` (could be a data.table as well, I just had no need for it so far).

How do I use values from two different objects to calculate a new column, if the factor level (here: `sample`) matches? I used to merge both objects and do it row for row, but this results in a vast amount of redundant data.

this is the data.frame, which only has 10 rows:

```
df

    sample scaling_factor
A1      A1      111956565
A2      A2       89869320
A3      A3      120925219
A4      A4      111757559
A5      A5       77319341
A6      A6       89403194
A7      A7      150214981
B8      B8      133885925
B9      B9       86536587
B10    B10      123574939


df <- structure(list(sample = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 10L, 8L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", 
"A7", "B10", "B8", "B9"), class = "factor"), scaling_factor = c(111956565.427018, 
89869319.9348599, 120925219.4453, 111757558.886234, 77319340.5841949, 
89403194.1170576, 150214980.784589, 133885925.080984, 86536586.7136393, 
123574939.026597)), .Names = c("sample", "scaling_factor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "B8", "B9", "B10"))
```

and this is the data.table, which has hundred thousands of lines per sample (dput had trouble with `<`in the output, so not provided here):

```
setDT(dt)
    sample     contig_id product_reads_rpk
 1:     A1     contig_10        2000.00000
 2:     A1    contig_100          24.27184
 3:     A1   contig_1000        1713.90374
 4:     A1  contig_10000        2900.66225
 5:     A1 contig_100003        1713.94231
 6:     A1 contig_100004        8575.23511
 7:     A1 contig_100004       11059.32203
 8:     A2 contig_100009        6923.67400
 9:     A2 contig_100010        1285.30259
10:     A2 contig_100015          84.74576

dt[,product_rpm := product_reads_rpk/(df$scaling_factor/1000000), by = sample]
```

I'm trying to generate a new column `product_rpm` in the dt, based on the corresponding value for each sample in `df`. How do I do that? I'm getting `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` but the shorter object length is 1 for e.g. `A1` in df, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why `merge` wouldn't work here. After merging, you could create a new column by dividing `scaling_factor` from `product_reads_rpk`.

Comment: @Noah well merging works perfect, but it is a huge amount of redundant data e.g. 100.000 rows with the same `scaling_factor`. I was hoping to find a more elegant solution (and in general to understand how to use two different objects with data.table)

Comment: Try something like `dt[setDT(df), product_rpm := product_reads_rpk / (scaling_factor / 1e6), on = .(sample)]`.

Comment: @crazysantaclaus you can't accept a comment, only an answer.

Comment: well that is true, but you could also formulate an answer out of your comment. I'm just not sure which solution is closer to the original task ("without merging"), as I don't know whether your code contains a hidden merging step?

Comment: What do you have against merging? It is not hidden, it is there. The answers are pretty much the same, so no need in posting another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way of doing this without actually merging the two datasets - but if you use the `data.table` way of merging datasets, you can avoid creating the redundant column.

So, in your case it would simply be:

```
df <- data.table(df)
dt[df, product_rpm := (product_reads_rpk/scaling_factor/1000000), on = "sample"]
```

A simple example:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(id = sample(1000:9999, size = 100),
                  size = sample(10000:99999, size = 100))

dt2 <- data.table(id = rep(dt1$id, 10), 
                  group = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 10),
                  value = sample(1000:9999, size = 100 * 10, replace = T))

dt3 <- dt2[dt1, metric:= (value / size), on = "id"]
head(dt3)
```

Comment: @David Arenburg: well, both solutions worked well and gave the same results (except for parentheses missing in royr2's answer around the `scaling_factor/1000000`. Can you tell me which should be the accepted answer, e.g. do you both include a "kind of merging" step in your code?

Comment: well, both solutions worked well and gave the same results (except for parentheses missing in royr2's answer around the scaling_factor/1000000. Can you tell me which should be the accepted answer, e.g. do you both include a "kind of merging" step in your code?